# Does EF CodeFirst create any Temp tables by default?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, temp-tables

I'm working on a project that uses EF code first style with Sql Server, and someone was wondering if EF uses or creates any temporary tables automatically.

I figured it might use some other temporary objects if it had to, but I'm not really sure.

Does Entity Framework create or use any temporary tables when setup for a CodeFirst project with default conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Grepping the sources there are only irrelevant matches for `CREATE TABLE`. There's nothing in EF's normal operations that does this.

Answer (score 1):

It does not create any temporary tables. However depending on which version of EF you are using, and whether or not you are using model migrations, it does create infrastructures table(s).

For example older versions create dbo.EdmMetadata, and newer versions create dbo.__MigrationHistory.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to pick yours, it was a toss-up.